# Can the target of Mind of Rage take normal actions on its turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, wizard

[Mind of Rage](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12767) (Wizard Attack 25 from HotFL) gives this effect:

> The target is affected by mind of rage (save ends). This effect also
>   ends if you or any of your allies attacks or deals damage to the
>   target. While the target is affected by mind of rage, at the start of
>   its turn it charges a creature of your choice as a free action. The
>   charge attack gains a +4 power bonus to the attack roll and the damage
>   roll. In addition, when an ally of the target ends its turn adjacent
>   to the target, the target makes a melee basic attack against that ally
>   as a free action.

Nowhere in the description it says it can't take normal conscious actions (like move and attack someone by itself). But since the aftereffect for the power is:

> The target is dazed until the end of its next turn.

Since a dazed condition gives the creature just one action and some other restrictions, I'm getting the impression that mind of rage does indeed prevent other actions from being made.

Can someone clarify that to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**,

The target has charged.  As a result it may only take free actions for the remainder of its turn.

It could use a free action to spend an action point to get a standard action for example.  But it could not use the normal move and standard actions that a creature normally gets.

Comment: That's right, in the context of this effect I didn't remember that.

Comment: When reading skills I always forget that charge means no more actions that turn.